# How to create a union of two tables with null values?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two MySQL tables, "ucharacters" and "uplaces," that both have the column "ucharacter." There is some overlap between the ucharacter columns in the two tables, but some values are unique to each. Each table also has columns for "episode" and "line," but the "uplaces" table also has a "place" column. This will create a simple version of this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ucharacters (
  ucharacter VARCHAR(50),
  episode INT(2),
  line INT(6)
  );

CREATE TABLE uplaces (
  ucharacter VARCHAR(50),
  episode INT(2),
  line INT(6),
  place VARCHAR(40)
  );

INSERT INTO ucharacters VALUES ('Molly', 4, 123);
INSERT INTO ucharacters VALUES ('Leo', 5, 567);
INSERT INTO uplaces VALUES ('Leo', 5, NULL, 'Athens');
```

I want to select from a temporary table that combines these, so that it preserves every line from each table, with NULL values as appropriate. The result would look like:

```
UCHARACTER  EPISODE LINE PLACE
Molly       4       123  NULL
Leo         5       567  NULL
Leo         7       NULL Athens
```

Here is my code now:

```
SELECT tabkey.ucharacter, 

ucharacters.episode, ucharacters.line, 

uplaces.episode, uplaces.line, uplaces.place

FROM 

(SELECT ucharacters.ucharacter FROM ucharacters
 UNION ALL
 SELECT uplaces.ucharacter FROM uplaces) as tabkey

LEFT JOIN

ucharacters on tabkey.ucharacter = ucharacters.ucharacter

LEFT JOIN

uplaces on tabkey.ucharacter = uplaces.ucharacter;
```

This works fine for the first line (Molly, 4, 123, NULL) but then gives two identical lines of (Leo, 5, 567, Athens), combining the two tables. How can I get the result I typed above instead?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7013e/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select from a temporary table that combines these, so that it preserves every line > from each table, with NULL values as appropriate. The result would look like:

If that is all you want to do, could you not simply use the query below?

```
SELECT ucharacter, episode, line, null FROM ucharacters
UNION ALL
SELECT ucharacter, episode, line, place FROM uplaces;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7013e/17/0